# JSch Multiple command issues?

Tags: java, jsch

I have this:

```
ChannelExec channel1 = (ChannelExec) session.openChannel("exec");
String command1 = "/opt/deluge/latest/bin/deluge-console -c ./.config/deluge";
String commandCon = "connect 127.0.0.1:2035";
String location = channelSftp.getHome();
String command2 = "add " + location + "/torrent1.torrent";
channel1.setCommand(command1 + "\n" + commandCon + "\n" + command2);
channel1.connect();
```

But it isn't adding the file I'm trying to add.

The full command I need is

```
/opt/deluge/latest/bin/deluge-console -c ./.config/deluge
```

Then once we started `deluge-console`, it does

```
connect 127.0.0.1:2035
```

to connect to the daemon and then

```
add /home/hd1/testuser/torrent1.torrent
```

I know my commands are correct as I can test them without using Java, but for some reason I'm not getting the result I'm expecting in my code above.

Answer (score 0):

The commands you specify using `.setCommand` are commands to be executed by the shell.

These are not equivalent to "lines", you enter on an SSH terminal.

So the `connect` command would be executed after the `deluge-console` exits, what never happens, as the `deluge-console` waits for its commands on its standard input.

---

Solutions are:

- Pipe the commands to the `deluge-console` like:

  ```
  (echo connect ... ; echo add ...) | deluge-console ...
  ```
- Feed the commands to the started `deluge-console` using standard input (`channel1.getOutputStream`)

  See [Sudo.java](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/examples/Sudo.java.html) JSch example.